# JSON to swift how to obtain the key value in a 2d array

Tags: json, swift

Here is my code and I'm banging my head against the wall for not being able to get the values from the JSON array correctly:

```
func loadPosts(posts:NSArray){
    for post in posts {
        var ter = (post["Territory"] as! String).toInt()
        var reg = (post["Region"] as! String).toInt()
        var stno = (post["Store"] as! String).toInt()
        var stname = post["StoreName"] as! String
        var goal = (post["Goal"] as! String).toInt()
        println(post)'
    }
}
```

- `println(ter)` displays the value "loadData.collection"
- `println(post)`  spits out all the nodes

What am I doing wrong here? Please help!!

---

Here is the JSON data out put

```
{
Goal = 0;
Region = 704;
Store = 10;
StoreName = "Mmn";
Territory = 1;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to cast it to the relevant type by using as? or as! then you can access the value.

Post json data for a better answer.

Comment: Where I should be casting?  I am already casting to String and then converting it to integer.